# FindEquationalProof with Logic in Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: warning-messages, logic, proof, theorem-proving

I try to "make" proof in Wolfram Mathematica.

Thats a proof:

> if a->b and b->c then a->c

I tried

```
bl = {ForAll[{a, b}, Implies[a, b]], ForAll[{b, c}, Implies[b, c]]}
proof = FindEquationalProof[ForAll[{a, c}, Implies[a, c]], bl]
```

but it say:

```
FindEquationalProof::invs: Invalid specification of propositions ... and axioms ...
```

How i can solve this problem??

Comment: What does the documentation say? The message you’re getting makes it pretty clear you’re not specifying your arguments correctly

Comment: `ForAll[{a, b}, Implies[a, b]]` doesn't really make sense though. It says that anything implies anything else.

Comment: The examples in the docs seem to have equations -- since it's in the name, it's probably important.

Comment: I take it that the idea is to construct a `ProofObject` for this proposition, not merely to get *Mathematica* to tell you it's true.  Is that correct?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yeah! I looking for `ProofObject`

Answer (score 9):

You don't need `FindEquationalProof` to this end, it is enough to use the quantifiers.

```
ForAll[{a, b, c}, Implies[Implies[a, b] && Implies[b, c], Implies[a, c]]];
Resolve[%]
```

> True

See Mathematica help for more info. If you insist to use `FindEquationalProof` here, then you may apply the following axioms of propositional logic

```
shefferLogic = {ForAll[a, nand[nand[a, a], nand[a, a]] == a],
ForAll[{a, b}, nand[a, nand[b, nand[b, b]]] == nand[a, a]],
ForAll[{a, b, c},  nand[nand[a, nand[b, c]], nand[a, nand[b, c]]] == 
nand[nand[nand[b, b], a], nand[nand[c, c], a]]]}
```

, reformulating your theorem in  terms of [the Sheffer stroke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke). Good luck!

Addition. One more way to prove it is to check whether the formula defines tautology.

```
BooleanTable[ Implies[Implies[a, b] && Implies[b, c], Implies[a, c]], {a, b, c}]
```

> {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}

It should be noticed that the formula under consideration is taken as an axiom in some systems of axioms of propositional calculus. See [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) for more info.