# FindEquationalProof with implications

Tags: proof, theorem-proving

Motivated by [this question in mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3086499/showing-a-conditional-statement-is-a-tautology-without-using-a-truth-table), my *Mathematica* question is essentially [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188952/findequationalproof-with-logic-in-wolfram-mathematica), but alas the answer to that isn't quite adequate.  I'm not interested in verifying that a proof is *valid* or true or represents a tautology, but instead in representing the intermediate steps in that proof, preferably graphically.

- Why isn't this format valid?  `myProof = FindEquationalProof[
  a \[DoubleRightArrow] c, {a \[DoubleRightArrow] b, 
  b \[DoubleRightArrow] c}]` . (I've tried all manner of existential qualifiers, parentheses instead of brackets, `Implies`, etc., as well.) . Note too that `FindEquationalProof[a == c, {a == b, b == c}]` works fine.
- How do I get the visualization, of the general form `myProof["ProofGraph"]`?

Comment: FindEquationalProof works with theorems and axioms in Equational Logic. That is, those theorems and axioms must be stated as equalities, using Equal. You can use your own operators, as long as you provide their axioms in equational form. In FindEquationalProof, there is no built-in meaning for any function other than Equal. FindEquationalProof does not know about And, Implies, Not, etc. Nor about Plus, Times, Minus, etc. Finally, note that \\[DoubleRightArrow] is not a logic operator in the Wolfram Language. It's a typesetting construct. Use Implies[p, q] for logic implication.

Comment: @jose:  Thanks for your insights.  Incidentally, I cut-and-pasted the \[DoubleRightArrow] from the Implies operator page from the *Mathematica* documentation, and indeed sometimes it is rendered in the output.  It seems that I must craft my own syntax if I want to solve my problem... or perhaps wait for Wolfram to incorporate inferential logic in a later release.

Comment: Indeed, there will be other proof constructors (other than FindEquationalProof) in the future, based on other logics. The ProofObject, however, will have the same form, using the general syntax ProofObject[logic, theorem, axioms, proofinfo]. The theorem and axioms must be expressed in the given logic, and the proofinfo will strongly depend on that logic. Currently logic is always "EquationalLogic".